# remove all flash objects without overloading browser

Tags: javascript, performance, flash

I'm loading on my site third party content. Now I'm trying to remove all flash objects from my page using header script code. The problem is that everything must load in browser and i can only remove flash objects after page was loaded. So what i did is working, but it is overloading the browser when my code remove flash object. Please tell me how to do that better ?

```
var all = document.getElementsByTagName("*");
for (var i=0, max=all.length; i < max; i++)swfobject.removeSWF(all[i].id);
```

i want to replace flash object with , like `all[i].parentNode.replaceChild(mydiv, all[i]);`
mydiv is an image which shows a warnning in place of flash object which is not allowed.

Do i need just to remove the flash object and then insert the warnning, or what to do to not overload the browser after I'm replacing the flash object.

I'm not using jquery on my website, so please advice using only native javascript
firefox browser is very busy... in task manager, i see FlashPlayerPlugin_11_7_700_224.exe  | CPU 21%

Comment: What do you mean by 'overload'? What exactly are you experiencing?

Comment: firefox browser is very busy... in task manager, i see FlashPlayerPlugin_11_7_700_224.exe  | CPU 21%

Comment: have a look at my answer , i've edited it for your special case

Answer (score 1):

The reason is because you're using the getElementsByTagName and passing it "*", which means you're looping through possibly thousands or tens of thousands of elements.

A better way to do this would be:

```
var allEmbeds = document.getElementsByTagName("embed");
// put code here to loop through and remove the embed elements
var allObjects = document.getElementsByTagName("object");
// put code here to loop through and remove the object elements, if they meet the criteria
```

You will need to do a check to see if each object is actually a Flash object. You can do that by checking if it has a classid attribute equal to "clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000" or a type attribute equal to "application/x-shockwave-flash".

Answer (score 1):

There is more elegant way. Why not to simply redefine some methods in the `swfobject` class? Try to do this, put this script after your  `<script>` tags:

```
swfobject = { 
    embedSWF : function(swfUrlStr, replaceElemIdStr){
        document.getElementById(replaceElemIdStr).innerHTML = yourWarningMessage;
    }, 
    removeSWF : function(){
        // Just do nothing!
    }
}
```

Or even this kind of redefinition:

```
for(var i in swfobject){
   if(typeof swfobject[i] == function){
      swfobject[i] = function(){};
   }
}
```

Comment: As i understood, you suggest to redefine swfobject method which is called when flash objects are trying to initialize, and this way your code will just not let the page to load flash object , right ?

Comment: @Jigberto exactly , win the enemy with minimum forces

Comment: very smart , i did not tried that yet, but i like how it sounds, thanks for your mind, i will always take that into my considerations because it is realy easy, smart and minimum as you say :)

Comment: @Jigberto yes!! it may be useful for some cases , so let me know if it works!

Comment: @Jigberto what exactly not working? is it throwing some errors?

Comment: if I will add this code:

`alert('before'); swfobject = { embedSWF : function(){}, removeSWF : function(){} } alert('after');`

will show nothing, maybe because javascript is wrong,  normaly it should alert before and after.

Comment: you need to use Chrome console to know exactly if there are some errors. and it will be better if you place `swfobject = { ... }` immediately after script tags in `head` tag

Comment: SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
get stack: function () { [native code] }
message: "Unexpected identifier"
set stack: function () { [native code] }
__proto__: Error

Comment: @Jigberto and a flash ads still appearing?

Comment: @Jigberto ok , i've updated my answer , try this in second way. just remember , you need to put this code immediately after `swfobject` script tag